# Sql performance query multiple conditions on same column

Tags: sql

I have a table ORDERS with ORDER_ID and SERVICE_ID field.

I can have multiple entries in table like:

```
ID   ORDER_ID   SERVICE_ID
1     000001         1
2     000001         2
3     000001         3

4     000002         1
5     000002         2
```

I need to final all orders that have entries for service_id 2 but not for service_id 3.
My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS
WHERE SERVICE_ID = 2
  AND ORDER_ID NOT IN (SELECT ORDER_ID FROM ORDERS WHERE SERVICE_ID = 3)
```

Is there another way to do this in order to improve performance?

Thanx

Comment: That depends largely on the DBMS product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` which generally performs better than `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS O
WHERE O.SERVICE_ID = 2
  AND NOT EXISTS 
      (SELECT 1 FROM ORDERS OO WHERE OO.ORDER_ID = O.ORDER_ID AND OO.SERVICE_ID = 3)
```

Comment: Note that NOT EXISTS has a different result than NOT IN if the subquery returns a null value.

Comment: And that is why NOT IN is not recommended.

Comment: True, in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this would be

```
select * from orders o1
where service_id = 2
and not exists (
   select * from orders o2
   where o1.order_id = o2.order_id
   and o2. service_id = 3)
```

But no one will be able to tell you whether any of these will give performance problems due to the following:

- As long as your data volume is small, performance will be good no matter how your query is written.
- When your query needs optimization, the DBMS optimizer will try to do its best. You can find out what it did and whether it suggests improvements using its "explain" feature (that's what it's called in MS SQL Server, might have a different name for your DBMS) on the actual query on the actual data.
- One way to optimize performance is to introduce an index for each attribute (combination) used as selection criteria. In your case that would be `order_id` and `service-id`.

Defining a few indexes isn't much work, so you might do it right beforehand. As for other precautions, I would wait until performance issues really turn up, which will probably never happen.

Comment: Note that NOT EXISTS has a different result than NOT IN if the subquery returns a null value.